# Get Taxonomy Terms, GUIDs, Synonyms (Other Labels) into Array within a SharePoint Page (not App)

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, term-store

I am using the code below to get terms (Later I will push these into an array). This is based on this article: [Working with Taxonomy and JavaScript in SharePoint 2013](http://www.vrdmn.com/2012/12/working-with-taxonomy-and-javascript-in.html)

It is pushing the term names, but I also need to get the term guid and synonyms. My goal is to have a nested dropdown somewhat like the one in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258168/nested-select-options) SO question.

So the goals are as follows:

1. Get all terms, synonyms, and guids pushed into an array

Here is my code for the taxonomy:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    execOperation();
});

function execOperation() {
    //Current Context
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    //Current Taxonomy Session
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
    //Term Stores
    var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
    //Name of the Term Store from which to get the Terms.
    var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_11111111111==");
    //GUID of Term Set from which to get the Terms.
    var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("1111111-111-111-11111111");
    var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();
    context.load(terms);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
        var termList = "Terms: \n";
        while (termEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();
            termList += currentTerm.get_name() + "\n";
        }
        alert(termList);
    }, function (sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to set permissions on pages in SharePoint.  They will run in the context of the user accessing the page.  As long as the user can read the terms, it should work.

Comment: Could it be because I am using a "slimmed" down version of an .aspx page? I will update my post with the slimmed down page

Comment: Also, how do I get the GUID and synonym values?

Comment: The only thing I can find for GUID on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312546.aspx) is `get_mergedTermIds()`.  Don't see anything for synonyms.  Does your code not work? If not, what errors are you getting?

Comment: I am getting term names, but not synonyms or ids

Comment: I have updated my post, as it is focused to guids and synonyms

Comment: I am able to get the GUID using get_id(), but don't see a method for getting the synonyms (labels).

Comment: Try `.getAllLabels()` on the term

Comment: It only returns an object, and not the individual terms. I am guessing I will need to iterate over them.

Comment: Yeah, it returns a label collection.  I don't know if these consist of synonyms or not.

Comment: It was worth a try.